# Retrieve data in Hive

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

I storing list into *hive* using below code:

```
@override
  Future<void> saveProperty(List? propertyEntity) async {
    try {
      final invoiceBox = await Hive.openLazyBox(_propertyBox);
      await invoiceBox.put('list', propertyEntity);
    } on CacheException catch (e) {
      throw CacheException(e.message);
    }
  }
```

When retrieve, I use *get* method:

```
 @override
  Future<List<PropertiesEntity>?> getPropertiesList() async {
    try {
      final propertiesBox = await Hive.openLazyBox(_propertyBox);
      if (propertiesBox.isEmpty) return [];

      var list = await propertiesBox.get('list');

      if (list == null) return [];

      return list.cast<PropertiesEntity>();
    } on CacheException catch (e) {
      throw CacheException(e.message);
    }
  }
```

But if I want to get a specific item, why it will return two items? I thought it should return items with specific index only?

```
@override
  Future<PropertiesEntity?> getPropertyDetails() async {
    try {
      final propertiesBox = await Hive.openLazyBox(_propertyBox);
      var propertyEntity = await propertiesBox.getAt(0); // this is the Listview's index
      debugPrint(propertyEntity.toString());
    } on CacheException catch (e) {
      throw CacheException(e.message);
    }
  }
```

**Output**

```
[Instance of 'PropertiesEntity', Instance of 'PropertiesEntity']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your case index is not enough you need to pass the index key

```
      @override
  Future<List<PropertiesEntity>?>  getPropertiesList() async {
    try {
      final propertiesBox = await Hive.openBox("data");
      List<PropertiesEntity>? allData =propertiesBox.get("propertyList");
      for(var j in allData!){
        print(j.name);
      }
     return allData;
    } catch (e) {
      print("data==========$e");
    }
  }




@override
Future<PropertiesEntity?> getPropertyDetails(int index) async {
try {
  final propertiesBox = await Hive.openBox("data");
   List<PropertiesEntity>? allData =propertiesBox.get("propertyList");
   print(allData!.length);
  var propertyEntity = allData.elementAt(index);
  print(propertyEntity.name);
  return propertyEntity;
 } catch (e) {
  print("data==========$e");
  }
}

 @override
 Future<void>saveProperty(List<PropertiesEntity> propertyEntity) async {
  try {
   final invoiceBox = await Hive.openBox("data");
   await invoiceBox.put("propertyList", propertyEntity);
  } catch (e) {
  print(e.toString());
  }
}
```

Comment: But what if my list[0] is not entity domain?

Comment: try like this if that solves you issue 
var propertyEntity = await propertiesBox.get(list<propertyEntity>[0].key); or just get(0);

Comment: ```E/flutter (14165): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'compareTo' was called on null.
E/flutter (14165): Receiver: null
E/flutter (14165): Tried calling: compareTo("list")```

Comment: This error pointed to this line `var propertyEntity = await propertiesBox.get(list[index].key);`

Comment: does your getPropertiesList() function working properly? because i am using your code only

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252888/discussion-between-john-joe-and-sagar-sable).

Comment: hey john, can we discuss this again?

Comment: thanks ! elementAt works for me